# Why assign a function to a $.x variable?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
(function ($) {
    /**
    * Opens a new modal window
    * @param object options an object with any of the following options
    * @return object the jQuery object of the new window
    */
    $.modal = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.modal.defaults, options),
            root = getModalDiv(),
```

Can someone explain why the function is given to the object $.modal and not just modal? Also what's the significance of the first line:

Comment: Because it is a jQuery plugin, they're defining it to run withing the jQuery namespace of "$".

Comment: @meagar: Since people always keep saying this to me in such situations: This is an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it is a jQuery plugin, they're defining it to run withing the jQuery namespace of `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) (`(function(){})()`) code outside of it couldn't access `modal`. Alternatively you could do it like this:

```
var holder = {};

(function($){
    holder.modal = function()
    };
})();

holder.modal();
```

Comment: Sure you can -- `modal = function(){}`.  Without `var`, `modal` would be available globally.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with closures. Local variables cannot be accessed from outside a function because they are that: **local**, whether the function is a closure or not. `(function(){})()` is an *immediately executed function expression* and you are right, the function itself is a closure, but so is every user-defined function.

Comment: To expand on josh3736's comment, if you simply typed `modal = function () { }`, this is identical to typing `window.model = function () { }`, and it would be available globally. Variables declared without `var` are implicitly attached to the `window` object (or whichever global context your JS environment is executing in). As Felix said, the question really has nothing to do with closures and everything to do with binding a jQuery plugin to the jQuery object instead of the global object.